# how to properly train TensorFlow on one machine and evaluate on another?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training a TensorFlow (1.2) model on one machine and attempting to evaluate it on another. Everything works fine when I stay local to one machine.

I am not using placeholders and feed-dict's to get data to the model but rather TF file queues and batch generators. I suspect with placeholders this would be much easier but I am trying to make the TF batch generator machinery work.

In my evaluation code I have lines like:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(os.path.dirname(ckpt_dir))
if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
```

This produces errors like:

```
017-08-16 12:29:06.387435: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Invalid argument: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to get matching files on /data/perdue/minerva/tensorflow/models/11/20170816/checkpoints-20: Not found: /data/perdue/minerva/tensorflow/models/11/20170816
```

The referenced directory (`/data/...`) exists on my training machine but not the evaluation machine. I have tried things like

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(
   '/local-path/checkpoints-XXX.meta',
   clear_devices=True
)
saver.restore(
    sess, '/local-path/checkpoints-XXX',
)
```

but this produces a different error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value train_file_queue/limit_epochs/epochs
```

or, if I explicitly call the initializer functions immediately after the restore,

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'initializer'
```

Here, `train_file_queue/limit_epochs/epochs` is an element of the training graph that I would like the evaluation function to ignore (I have another, new element `test_file_queue` that is pointing at a different file queue with the evaluation data files in it).

I think in the second case when I'm calling the initializers right after the restore that there is something in the local variables that won't doesn't work quite like a "normal" Tensor, but I'm not sure exactly what the issue is.

If I just use a generic `Saver` and `restore` TF does the right thing on the original machine - it just restores model parameters and then uses my new file queue for evaluation. But I can't be restricted to that machine, I need to be able to evaluate the model on other machines.

I've also tried freezing a protobuf and a few other options and there are always difficulties associated with the fact that I need to use file queues as the most upstream inputs.

What is the proper way to train using TensorFlow's file queues and batch generators and then deploy the model on a different machine /  in a different environment? I suspect if I were using feed-dict's to get data to the graph this would be fairly simple, but it isn't as clear when using the built in file queues and batch generators.

Thanks for any comments or suggestions!

Comment: (I would assume) you are saving into `ckpt_dir`, but then you do `os.path.dirname(ckpt_dir)` which will give you the _parent_ directory. Is that what you intended?

Comment: The issue is not the path to the checkpoint directory. As I said, everything works on one machine. So, I can train and evaluate on machine A or I can train and evaluate on machine B, but I cannot train on machine A and evaluate on machine B. When you call `save.restore()` it complains it can't find directory paths from the other machine - so these paths are stored inside the checkpoint files. I suspect they are part of the batch queue elements in the graph, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Try to use MonitoredTrainingSession, it loads and saves the checkpoints automatically. It might help. I also have issues with tensorflow 1.2 when I do not want all the graph to be evaluated, it does it anyway and sometimes fails. I didn't have this issue with 1.3. Also try this code to restore after you have created the model: `saver.restore(session, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoints_dir))`

Answer (score 1):

At least part of the answer to this dilemma was answered in TF 1.2 or 1.3. There is a new flag for the `Saver()` constructor:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(save_relative_paths=True)
```

that makes it such that when you save the checkpoint directory and move it to another machine, and use it to `restore()` a model, everything works without errors relating to nonexistent paths for the data (the paths from the old machine where training was performed).

It isn't clear my use of the API is really idiomatic in this case, but at least the code works such that I can export trained models from one machine to another.